# FREEIPA Identity Provider server: Azure Active Directory

Tags: ldap, active-directory, freeipa, azure

I am trying to add AAD as the identity server provider in Freeipa and configured it as shown in the below screenshot.
[image]

There isn't much available in the documentation. Can anyone help with what else is needed to make it work?